# Generate CSR in Java using openssl and -subj parameter

Tags: java, process, openssl

I'm generating private `.key` and `.csr` and then the certificate using `openssl` and `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` in java. I have given `-subj` parameter in `.csr` command to make it non interactive, following is my code

```
public void generate(String name) {
    String[] cmds = new String[4];

    String subject = "-subj /C=PK/ST=Sindh/L=Karachi/O=Company Pvt Ltd/OU=IT Department/CN=Developer";
    String configFile = "conf.cnf";

    cmds[0] = String.format("openssl genrsa -out %s.key 2048", path+name);
    cmds[1] = String.format("openssl req -new -key %s.key -out %s.csr %s", path+name, path+name, subject);
    cmds[2] = String.format("openssl x509 -req -in %s.csr -CA %s.pem -CAkey %s.key -CAcreateserial -out %s.crt -days 365 -sha512 -extensions mysection -extfile %s", path+name, path+rootName, path+rootName, path+name, path+configFile);
    cmds[3] = String.format("openssl pkcs12 -export -out %s.pfx -inkey %s.key -in %s.crt", path+name, path+name, path+name);

    try {

        Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds[0]);

        // exhaust input stream
        exhaustInputStream(p1);
        p1.waitFor();

        Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds[1]);            

        // exhaust input stream
        exhaustInputStream(p2);
        p2.waitFor();

        Process p3 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmds[2]);            

        // exhaust input stream
        exhaustInputStream(p3);
        p3.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

the issue is when above `.csr` command executes it results in an error

> unknown option Pvt

this is because of spaces in here `Company Pvt Ltd`

I tried the same command with

```
String subject = "-subj /C=PK/ST=Sindh/L=Karachi/O=Company%20Pvt%20Ltd/OU=IT%20Department/CN=Riksof";
```

It generates the certificate but doesn't convert the `%20` with space, and also generate the corrupted `.csr`

Comment: Have you tried having a '\' before each space? And if you have a choice use Python or another scripting language instead of Java.

Comment: Java is the only option

Comment: Try like this:
"-subj /C=PK/ST=Sindh/L=Karachi/O=\"Company Pvt Ltd\"/OU=IT%20Department/CN=Company"

Comment: Still same issue `unknown option Pvt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the overload of `exec()` that takes a `String[]` argument, which in turn means you need to define your formats as `String[]` as well.

**Update:**

following is the code

```
String[] csrCmd = {
    "openssl",
    "req",
    "-new",
    "-key",
    path+name + ".key",
    "-out",
    path+name + ".csr",
    "-subj",
    "/C=PK/ST=Sindh/L=Karachi/O=Company Pvt Ltd/OU=IT Department/CN=Developer"
};

Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(csrCmd);
```

Comment: Also I think its not necessary to convert command in `String[]` since there is another overload that expects `String` command and `String[]` envp `exec(String command, String[] envp)`

Comment: @riksof-zeeshan EJP is asking to use the exec(String[] cmd). The envp (environment variables) is something else.

Comment: @riksof-zeeshan I am *telling* you that it *is* necessary. Try it before you debate this further. If your code was working you wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: @riksof-zeeshan I'd rather not have the pointless argument than have the pointless flattery.